# GAE session. java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.cs.UTF_8 issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, exception

I am pretty new to Google App Engine and have encountered an issue when i deployed my new application for the first time.
I am trying to store some objects in a session. Everything has been working fine on my localhost.
The stack trace below points me to the class "Group" not being serializable - But it is. Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

```
/CreateGroup.action
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.cs.UTF_8
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.serialize(SessionManager.java:358)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore.createEntityForSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:71)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore.saveSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:93)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager$AppEngineSession.save(SessionManager.java:153)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:41)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:391)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:160)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.cs.UTF_8
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
    at com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.model.Group.writeObject(Group.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:962)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1018)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:962)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.serialize(SessionManager.java:355)
    ... 23 more
```

---

Group.java has these fields (The type CommonPool is also implementing Serializable):

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Group implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5274228818084728571L;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent
    private int memberCount;

    @Persistent
    private int maxMemberCount;

    @Persistent
    private String currencySymbol;

    @Persistent
    private String url;

    @Persistent
    private Date createdOn;

    @Persistent
    private CommonPool pool;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've "overridden" the magic writeObject method to customize how Group is Serialized, and somewhere in there is an instance of sun.nio.cs.UTF_8. You say CommonPool is Serializable, but just implementing the interface doesn't make it so. It has to actually be serializable, or it'll fail. There's also a "Key" there. That could be the source of your problem, too.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply.
Overriding writeObject sounds like a mystery to me ;-) And i am pretty sure i haven't done that.
The fields of CommonPool are just of types double and String also Key as you pointed out in class Group. The type Key is just the standard com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key of app engine datastore which i would believe is serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out (and I do feel a bit embarrassed)
There was a field the in Group.java that i had overlooked (not in the code stub above) and which was not serializable ... stupid me.
Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you Ryan for your quick response.